# Python Sorting Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, sorting

Hi making a file that sorts through a txt file and selects the name: and the first 3 stats and stores them in a dict then does the same for the next name + 3 stats if dict isn't smart storing them in a list would work also I think.

### the txt file looks like this:

```
player a 34 45 56 player b 38 93 75 playerc 39 29 18 playerd 38 98
```

I tried `player = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", player_string)`
But it only gives me the player ratings and I think I need to use some kind of dict to store all the different players.

If this is complicated you don't have to do the entire thing for me just point me in the right direction.
Thank you.
I'm using py2.6

Comment: Does the file really consist of a single long line?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: yeah it's just a long line of text, with the awkward spaces.

Comment: Desired output is just a list or dictonary so that i can call the player and bring up the 3 stats that are assoicated with the name

Comment: what about player a vs playerc? is that a typo? Perhaps you should post a short sample of your actual input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is:

```
import re

player_string = "player a 34 45 56 player b 38 93 75 playerc 39 29 18 playerd 38 98"

pattern = re.compile(r"([\w ]*?)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)")
matches = pattern.findall(player_string)
d = {}
for m in matches :
    print m
    d[m[0].strip()] = m[1:]

print d
```

After the last player "playerd" you only have 2 numbers, not 3 as regex expects.

Output:

```
{'playerc': ('39', '29', '18'), 'player b': ('38', '93', '75'), 'player a': ('34', '45', '56')}
```

Comment: @ Mihai yeah that was so if the value isnt present I just wanted it to be a zero

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is:

```
import re

player_string = "player a 34 45 56 player b 38 93 75 playerc 39 29 18 playerd 38 98"

pattern = re.compile(r"player\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)")
matches = pattern.findall(player_string)
d = {}
for m in matches :
    print m
    d[m[0]] = m[1:]

print d
```

Pay attention that you wrote "playerc" and "playerd" without spaces and these 2 will not be found.

Comment: yeah did that on purpose because I can't be certain some names might be like Mike Jones or Clark Kent or Maxpower the variation is what im having such a tough time with.

Comment: @user3496483 then what if a player is named 33 77 91? Are you generating this data? It would probably be easier to parse if you quoted it.

Comment: So you mean that in your example "player a" is the player's full name, also "playerc" is the player's full name. I.e. "player" is not just a delimiter is the actual name, correct? Is this case the regex has to be fixed.

Comment: @Mihai yeah that's right sorry for not being more clear mihai

Answer (score 0):

I think this might give you something like what you are looking for, albeit not using a regex:

```
my_list = # list of players and stats from above

# build a list by splitting the original string at the word "player"
# and stripping extra white space
my_list_split = [item.strip() for item in my_list.split("player")]
```

This gives a list like `['', 'a 34 45 56', ...]` where each element should contain the information for a different player. Next we split the elements up into a dictionary where the player names are the keys and the stats are the values:

```
my_dict = {}  # initialize the dictionary
for entry in my_list_split:
  if entry is not "":  # possible you will have a blank string at the beginning
    entry_list = entry.split(" ")  # split entry at spaces
    my_dict[entry_list[0]] = entry_list[1:]  # first element is the name, remaining elements are the stats
```

You could modify this some to only get the first two or three stats, or to change the way that the stats are stored or something. The resulting `my_dict.items()` on the list that you gave is:

```
[('a', ['34', '45', '56']),
 ('c', ['39', '29', '18']),
 ('b', ['38', '93', '75']),
 ('d', ['38', '98'])]
```